# Windows 8 Metro Start Menu Tile Rows

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

None of the available registry hacks or customisation tools appear to be able to increase the number of rows I have available in the Metro start interface.

I'm running at 1920x1080 but only have 3x rows of tiles.

Any way of increasing this?

eg: http://www.onebitzero.com/change-the-number-of-app-rows-displayed-in-windows-8-start-screen-how-to/

[image]

when changed some of these revert to "3" on log out/log in

OK this is crazy; 
at 1776x1000 I get 4x rows;
at 1680x1050 I get 5x rows;
at 1920x1080 I get 3x rows

Guess that's why they call it a "Preview"...

Comment: Perhaps let us know which "registry hacks" and "customisation tools" you've tried already.

Answer (score 3):

**Number of rows in the start screen can be tweaked by editing the registry.**

*NOTE: Before making changes to the registry, it is recommended that you back it up or create a restore point.*

1. Open the registry editor.

   [image: Open Registry Editor]
2. Navigate to the following key in the left pane.

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Grid
3. Look for the Layout_MaximumRowCount value in the list on the right. It’s most likely not there. If not, select New | DWORD (32-bit) Value from the Edit menu to create a new value.

   [image]
4. A new value is created and the text for it highlighted. Rename the value “Layout_MaximumRowCount” (without the quotes). Double-click on the new value to edit it.

   [image]
5. On the Edit DWORD (32-bit) Value dialog box, select Decimal as the Base and enter the desired number of rows in the Value data edit box. The maximum number of rows is five. Click OK.

   [image]
6. Close the registry editor. You must log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.